Is there a general numerical solving algorithm for any arbitrary equation?
I would like to ask, is there any generally universal (iterative) numerical algorithm for solving arbitrary equations, not requiring derivatives (i. e. unlike Newton's method), without the need of a starting point (i. e. able to obtain such guess automaticaly, even if the solved equation is not continuous/not everywhere defined) and that always converges to one (of possible many) roots (if there is such)?
Mathematicaly stated:
Given $f(x):A \rightarrow B$, such that $A,B\subseteqℂ$.
Give an algorithm that for any given $A,B$ can numerically find such x, that $f(x)=0$.
Or given there is not, state (or link) a proof of it (if such proof exists).

For algebraic equations, derivatives can be automatically obtained, without "explicitly" writing it out. This is called automatic differentiation.

But for general functions, root finding is not possible algorithmically. This is due to functions that "hover" above the x-axis for a long time. They prevent any progress for iterative algorithms, and you can't get any convergence guarantees whatsoever.

For finding the roots of an arbitrary continuous function without requiring derivatives you're probably stuck with (some form of) bisection. You don't need a starting point, but you need a starting interval. If you drop the requirement of continuity, you need to handle all sorts of weird functions, and there isn't necessarily a root.

No, there isn't. Otherwise it would be offered as "solves all" function in pocket calculators. There are 'pathological' cases that fail numerical 'attack'.

I addressed the lack of exact statement of my question, please account for them in your answers.

If $f$ can be any function, then consider $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\ne\alpha\ 0 & \text{ if } x=\alpha \end{cases}$ where alpha is a random real number. There is obviously no algorithm that can find the root since that's equivalent to guessing a random real number.

@jjagmath An algorithm could look at the grammar of the statement and numerically approximate $\alpha$ .

Nelder Mead on $f^2$ is pretty general

@DanielV -- algorithms looking at the grammar of statements belong to numerical solving methods?

@DanielV "grammar of the statement"? Which statement?

@jjagmath The definition of f(x) .  The actual text used to define f.  Like "if it is a polynomial do this, but if it is a quotient of polynomials, do that, and if it is relations combined by propositional logic, do another thing."

@m-stgt As the first step of every numerical solving method is to verify that the statement is in a form that can be solved using the numerical technique, it is not "belong to" but "is part of every".

@DanielV -- You say, "As the first step of every numerical solving method is to verify that the statement is in a form that can be solved using the numerical technique." The calculators I know (HP15C, HP42S) lack this first step you describe like a fact. That would need some CAS capabilities. In contrast both models start solving for example $x^2+2$ to find soon "no solution".

@DanielV What make you think that you have access to the text defining $f$? In any algorithm functions are always considered as black boxes, where you feed an input and get an output. Otherwise algorithms will depend on the implementation of the function.

I feel like any such algorithm would violate some sort of "no free lunch" theorems/principles. There are hard results of this type in optimization and I suspect that they are true for rootfinding as well, especially if the objective function is nonsmooth
